# Mathematica: How to create a function that returns a property similar to how LinearModelFit works?

Tags: attributes

I'm trying to write a custom function in Mathematica, `myFunc[x]`. I want to be able to define properties of the function so that the user can call `myFunc[x]["Property"]` and have it return the value stored in `Property`.

Basically I'm looking for the same functionality as `lmf=LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` where you can use `lmf["RSquared"]` to return the correlation coefficient of the fit, but `lmf[5]` returns the y value for x=5.

Here's an example of the function that I'm trying to define:

```
myFunc[data_]:=Module[
   {localProperty, x},
   localProperty = "123abc";
   Return[data+3x];
];
```

And the output should look like:

```
(* User enters normal data *)
In[1]: foo = myFunc[5]
Out[1]: 5+3x

(* User enters the name of the property *)
In[2]: foo["localProperty"]
Out[2]: "123abc"

(* User wants to enter a value and evaluate *)
In[3]: foo[3]  (* 5+3*3 *)
Out[3]: 14
```

Is there a way to do this? I believe it's a built-in capability, as witnessed by the symbolic `FittedModel` object, but all my searches have so far yielded nothing of use. I've looked at `Property`, `Option`, `Attributes`, and just using `If` statements to try and catch the cases where the user types in a property name.

I'm using Mathematica 8.

Thanks,

**Edit: Solution Found**

Thanks to the guys below, I've found my solution and now have a function that will fit a linear model and plot up the data in one go. I can also extract the model or model parameters by entering different options. Below is the code if anyone is interested.

```
Clear[ListPlotWithTrendline];
ListPlotWithTrendline[data_, addopts___] := Module[
   {lmf, lmfPlot, plot, plots, dr, lmfPlotMinX, lmfPlotMaxX, pos, pr, addopts2, lmfpr, returnValue},
   dr = {Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]};

   (* The workaround to get my 'opts' variable to work with Plot *)
   addopts2 = Flatten[{addopts}, 1];
   pos = Quiet[Check[Position[Map[StringSplit[ToString[#]][[1]] &, addopts2], "PlotRange"][[1, 1]], 0]];
   pr = Quiet[Check[ToExpression[addopts2[[pos, 2]]], dr]];
   (* Routine to extract plotrange values for use in the extrapolation *)
   lmfpr = If[
     pos > 0,
     Evaluate[Which[

       (* Both X and Y ranges are given *)
       Dimensions[pr] == {2, 2}, {pr[[1, 1]], pr[[1, 2]]},

       (* The X value is All or Automatic, so we use dataRange *)
       pr[[1]] === All || pr[[1]] === Automatic || pr[[1]] === Full, dr,

       (* The X range is given and Y is Full, All, or Automatic *)
       Length[pr] == 2 && Length[pr[[1]]] == 2, {pr[[1, 1]], pr[[1, 2]]},

       (* Only the Y range is given or there was some error, so use the dataRange *)
       True, dr
       ]],
     dr];
   lmf = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
   lmfPlot = Plot[lmf[x], {x, lmfpr[[1]], lmfpr[[2]]}, #] &@addopts2;
   plot = ListPlot[data, #] &@addopts2;
   plots = Show[plot, lmfPlot];

   (* Define the return values, based on what property the user is interested in. *)
   returnValue["FittedModel"] = lmf;
   returnValue["Plot"] = plots;
   returnValue["FitPlot"] = lmfPlot;
   returnValue["ScatterPlot"] = plot;
   returnValue["RSquared"] = lmf["RSquared"];
   returnValue["Slope"] = lmf[[1, 2, 2]];
   returnValue["Intercept"] = lmf[[1, 2, 1]];
   Return[returnValue];
   ];
```

I'm sure it's not the most efficient or clean code around, but it works so I'm happy. :-) Here's an example:
[image: Example of ListPlotWithTrendline]

Comment: Oh crap, thanks Szabolcs. I didn't notice that I was at stackoverflow. I'll flag it.

Comment: It's not off topic here, it was just a suggestion that you post on Mathematica.SE as answers come more quickly there.

Comment: Yeah that's where I normally go. But your answer below works, so yay! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example that should help:

```
In[1]:= 
makeFoo[] := foo @@ RandomInteger[10, 3]
foo[first_, _, _]["First"] := first
foo[_, second_, _]["Second"] := second
foo[_, _, third_]["Third"] := third
foo[a_, b_, c_][x_] := a x^2 + b x + c

In[6]:= f = makeFoo[]
Out[6]= foo[4, 2, 9]

In[7]:= f["Second"]
Out[7]= 2

In[8]:= f[x]
Out[8]= 9 + 2 x + 4 x^2
```

For the record:

Definitions of the form `f[...] := ...` are called [DownValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html).

Definitions of the form `f[...][...] := ...` (or with more levels, as in `f[...][...]...[...] := ...`) are called `SubValues` (the function doesn't seem to be documented but it works exactly the same way as `DownValues`).

Comment: Cool, thanks. It took a little bit of work and I had to add an option for what I wanted to do, but everything's working well thanks to this answer. I now have a function that will plot up a scatterplot and the fitted line of data, and can also return the slope, Rsq, and intercept.

Answer (score 8):

For your specific problem, the following piece of code will work

```
In[1]:=  myFunc[data_] := Module[{result},
            result["property"] = "123abc";
            result[v_] := data + v*3;
            Return[result];
         ];

In[2]:=  a=myFunc[10];
         a["property"]
         a[x]

Out[2]=  123abc
         10 + 3x
```

Comment: So this appears to just be another way of setting the downvalues that Szabolcs described. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, it is!  In fact, it is the same with the definition of `myFunc` as well.   The alternative would be to return a list of rules, then you can use `result/.Property` to retrieve it, similar to what you would find in the return of `Solve`.  You will find it quite powerful and convenient either way.

Comment: You can safely replace `Return[result];` by `return` (note the lack of semicolon).

Comment: @dthor yes, this solution creates a new unique symbol (using `Module`) and sets `DownValues` on it.   It's a different solution.  My solution uses `SubValues` and the very same head (`foo`) every time.  So here you'll have "objects" named similar to `result$123` and my solution will give you objects such as `foo[...]`.  I think both are good solutions.